# How to prevent a folder from being cut, copied or opened from others?

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a folder which is with in the www folder (`/wamp/root/www`). I need to prevent this folder from being cut, copied and opened from others.

Is there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the permissions to allow read, write, and execute permissions by specific user or group. The permissions are accessible through Folder Properties > Security.

See [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-do-i-secure-windows-xp-ntfs-files-and-shares/6152061) for details on the specific procedure. You will want to give yourself and the web server process "Full Control" permissions, and give everyone else no permissions.

Note that the web server (XAMPP) most likely runs as a *different user and group* to you. Giving yourself read/write permissions does not automatically let XAMPP read and write the folder. This can be the source of all kinds of entertaining permissions errors.

Comment: Can Apache recognisable windows folder permissions though ? , as XAMPP runs an apache server so im not sure if it would see the permissions or not ?.

Comment: Good point. I'm not actually sure how Apache handles permissions on Windows (and since I don't have access to a Windows computer right now, I can't try it.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a program named [Prevent](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Prevent-Download-139078.html), that does this.  Download it , try it.